# omni channel not routing to specified queue but when test in debug it does

Tags: queue, omnichannel

I have set up an omni channel to route to a specific queue based on the email address the case is coming from.  This works sometimes.  I have a couple of instances where it went to the general (default) queue but when I run debug in the flow it routes it where it should have gone.  What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @wendy did you find a solution and would you care to share your approach? I am giving the same to filter messages from xxxx@xxx.com to a certain queue?